# Does resistance effect of level 5 save us from damage given by other players in multiplayer server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to beat my friends in Minecraft. So I want to know if the resistance effect will help me to get zero damage from other players.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not take damage at all, use a much powerful command:

```
effect give @p minecraft:resistance infinite 255 true
```

Comment: Resistance 256 is not necessary. Each level of Resistance blocks 20% of damage, so Resistance 5 will block 100% of damage.